# ReactCSSTransitionGroup troubles - trying to get smooth slide in/out animation

Tags: css, animation, reactjs

I'm writing a questionnaire system in react and want to get the questions smoothly transitioning in and out.

Here's the render method for my component that displays the questions within.

```
render () {
    const { loadingQuestion, question, userId, actions } = this.props;

    const q = this.renderQuestion(question, (...args) => actions.answerQuestion(userId, ...args), (...args) => actions.skipQuestion(userId, ...args));
    return (
        <ul className="questions">
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="question"
                transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
            >
                {q}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

And also the css I'm using at the moment to achieve the vertical transition:

```
.question-enter {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
.question-enter.question-enter-active {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
.question-leave {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
.question-leave.question-leave-active {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
   transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Here's a link to a page showing the current behaviour:
http://price-it.co:8080/frame

Does anyone know why this css doesn't cause the question to slide out and instead just causes it to disappear?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you given `key` for each question under `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`?

Comment: Sorry - yes each question has its own key .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not working in my browser (I got `app.js:12Redux DevTools could not render. Did you forget to include DevTools.instrument() in your store enhancer chain before using createStore()?` error).

But I could say I have the same kind of experience with `CSSTransitionGroup`, so I decided to use `<TransitionGroup>` with `Velocity` instead - sure it's a little bit more jQuery-style, but it obviosely works better then css animation.

Comment: You could see how it works at `https://beta.sgoomys.com/user/parakhod`, you need to register first (login via social network now is not working) - all the accordion elements are animated using `'velocity-animate'`